# Azure Premium Functions - Control outbound traffic with Azure Firewall

Tags: azure-functions, azure-virtual-network, azure-storage-account

##### What I'm trying to achieve

I have a very simple Azure Function app in a Function Premium plan. I would like to control its outbound traffic so only the requests to, let's say ***[www.server.com](http://www.server.com)*** are allowed.

##### What I have tried so far

- I followed this instruction for an Azure App Service app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/network-secure-outbound-traffic-azure-firewall.
- I enabled the `Microsoft.Storage` Service Endpoint for the vnet/subnet that is integrated with the function app.
- I added the same vnet/subnet to the `Firewalls and virtual networks` settings of the storage account used by this function app.

##### Issue

When I was trying to add a new HttpTrigger function to this function app, I always got this error: `Failed to create HttpTrigger1: Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime.`

Sometimes I was getting this `Azure Functions runtime is unreachable` error on the `Functions` page:

[image: Screenshot of Azure Functions runtime is unreachable]

Sometimes I was also seeing this error on the `Overview` page of this function app:

[image: Screenshot of the error on the Overview page]

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be many causes that exists for this kind of errors `Azure Functions runtime is unreachable`:

1. As mentioned in the troubleshooting steps of the above error in [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account), the most common reason for this is that the function app has lost access to its storage account.

One of the workaround I did here:

Created the Azure Function (`.Net 3.1` Stack) - Premium Plan in the Azure Portal with Http Trigger with `VNet` Integration and configured Outbound IP Access.

It is running successfully.

[image]

Below are the resources associated with this function app.

[image]

As stated in the above documentation to get that kind of runtime **unreachable** error, I deleted the storage account associated with this Function App.
[image]

After that deletion of associated storage account, it has given the same error "`Azure Functions Runtime is unreachable`"

[image]

Recovered the deleted storage account and run the function again:

[image]

Make sure your storage account is not deleted which is associated with that function app, otherwise the function won't work.

2. Check the Storage account connection string whether it is deleted or overridden. For example `AzureWebJobsStorage` is the local storage emulator connection string variable set in `local.settings.json` used in running the function locally. The same variable has a different value in the Azure portal used to run the function in azure. So, make sure that all the properties related to the storage account are available and correct.
3. If you set the firewall in the storage account and are not configured to allow traffic to and from functions, please allow it.
4. If your daily usage quota is full, then the function runtime will not work. To resolve this, increase or remove the daily quota limit and restart your function app. Otherwise, the execution of your function app is blocked until the next day.
5. Please check your function app has allowed your IP address in inbound IP restrictions, which might be configured to block internet access.
6. If your function is hosted in ***Internally load-balanced App Service Environment***, please check the internal IP address is allowed because you might be configured to block inbound internet traffic so that the `function runtime is unreachable`.
7. Make sure you set the correct value of `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` in Configuration (Application Settings) in the Azure Portal Function App as that is the function runtime version setting and refresh the function app/re-deploy the function.
   As I created the Function App of `.Net Core 3.1` Stack so the compatible function runtime version is **3**.

[image]

---

> System.Private.CoreLib.Access to the path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\host.json' is denied

I'm able to access **host.json**, **function.json** files available in the Kudu console and also in the editor:

[image]

1. When you connected the Premium Function to **VNet** Integration, then make sure these two settings were available and the same.

[image]

There were few resolutions regarding this kind of error, please refer to this [MSFT Q&A Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/553848/azure-functions-access-to-restricted-storage-accou.html) and [GitHub Thread](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1349)

Comment: Really appreciate the detailed answer! I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry I was tied up by other tasks before I could find some time to try it again. I looked through your suggestions and verified that I wasn't missing anything. Then I deleted all the existing resources and re-created everything. It's really strange that this time all is working as expected. I don't think I did anything differently. So I guess it might be a timing issue or something like that? I really liked your troubleshooting steps, which are very comprehensive.